# Получение SQL из Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-model

Как увидеть необработанные `SQL`- запросы, которые выполняет `Django-Orm`?

```
queryset = Post.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `queryset` есть атрибут `query`

```
queryset = Post.objects.all()
print(queryset.query)
```

Вывод на экран

```
>>> SELECT "category"."id", "category"."title" FROM "category"
```